# How to write Custom Regular Expression to validate decimal float number 0.001 to 0.800 only?

Tags: regex

I am creating a form input field where user are allowed to input decimal number range 0.001 to 0.8 (or 0.800) only. I could not find a way with how to write custom regular expression? Kindly help me out?

Comment: Why not parse the number and validate if it's within that range?

Comment: Can you provide more context? this is Web? what are you using for this web development.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
0\.(8[0]{1,2}|[0-7][\d\d]{1,2})$
```

- `0\.` - Starting with *"0."*
- A group with the following condition:

  - *"800"*(`8[0]{1,2}`) or(`|`) anything under *"799"*(`[0-7][\d]{1,2}`)
  - `[0]{1,2}` and `[\d]{1,2}` will make 2nd and 3rd decimal numbers optional
- `$` will guarantee the whole number is validated

Comment: That won't allow numbers with only one or two digits after the decimal point, or without the leading zero, for example `.45` or `0.8`.

Comment: @RoToRa ok, fixed.

Comment: Thanks. It's work now

Comment: It still doesn't work.  It matches 0.000 which is not permitted.  And it also matches values with more than three digits to the right of the decimal point.  e.g. .070000.

Comment: Now it is matching `0.000000000`. `[00]*` is the same that `0*`, `[\d\d]*` is the same that `\d*`

Comment: @NyiNyiLin fixed the regex based on comments.

Comment: @NyiNyiLin But could not fix the `0.000` problem as related.

Comment: Hi folks, could you help expression for this range 00.01 to 20.00 ?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean a HTML form element, then you don't need a regular expression. An input element with `type="number"` has the attributes `min`, `max` and `step` that validates the number:

```
<input name="something" type="number" min="0.001" max="0.8" step="0.001">
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Comment: Agreed with the number input

Answer (score 0):

The following meets the requirement as stated in the question.

It matches 0.001 thru 0.800.

The leading zero left of the decimal point is optional and trailing zeros are optional not to exceed a number in the form of #.### between 0.001 and .800 inclusive.

```java
 "0?\\.(8(0)?(0)?|[0-7]\d[1-9]|[1-7]\d[0-9]|[1-7](0)?(0)?|[1-7][0-9])";
```